# startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) how to retrieve the extra bundle option?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

According to the Android documentation [public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)).

I can not figure it out how to retrieve the extra bundle options that I am passing on the intent.

I want to pass an ArrayList with data as an extra bundle option when I am calling the startActivityForResult method.

Sample of code:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("test1");
        list.add("test2");

        Bundle bundleOptions = new Bundle();
        bundleOptions.putStringArrayList("key", list);

startActivityForResult(intent, 10, bundleOptions);
```

Upon retrieving the data:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)

Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
```

Bundle extras does not contain the extra bundle that I am trying to pass. What I am missing and I can not retrieve the extra Bundle data that I am passing to the method?

I also tried with `intent.putExtra("key", bundleOptions);`, also with `intent.putExtra("key", list);` but with no success either and calling the method `startActivityForResult(intent, 10);` but again with no success.

I am sure that I am missing something does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Where do you execute the call from ? Fragment ? Activity ? where is the `onActivityResult` in ? Is the `Intent data` null or just empty ?

Comment: I execute from an Activity in one class and I retrieve the data in another class. The code works fine, I am trying to pass extra parameters on the retrieving activity. Thanks for your time and effort to assist me.

Comment: Are you sure the sending Activity is still alive while the result callback called ?

Comment: That is a question that I do not know, how can I be sure about that? I can retrieve the data of the intent, but not the extra parameters that I am trying to pass.

Comment: Start by adding log messages on the activity `onDestroy` and in the Result callback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Bundle extras does not contain the extra bundle that I am trying to pass.

Correct.

> What I am missing

If you wish to retrieve a value using `getExtras()`, [use `putExtras()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras%28android.os.Bundle%29) or individual `putExtra()` methods.

> I can not retrieve the extra Bundle data that I am passing to the method?

That third parameter to `startActivity()`/`startActivityForResult()` are to pass options to Android itself, not to pass data to another activity.

> I also tried with... intent.putExtra("key", list); but with no success either

In general, that works. For example, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Activities/Extras) has worked since Android 1.0. The launcher activity uses `putExtra()` to add a string extra; the other activity uses `getStringExtra()` to get the value.

If you have continued problems using `putExtra()`, post a separate Stack Overflow question, where you supply your code for setting and retrieving the extra, along with a detailed description of your symptoms.

Comment: That is perfect, I think I misunderstood how to use the startActivityForResult(). Since you mentioned "That third parameter to `startActivity()`/`startActivityForResult()` are to pass options to Android itself, not to pass data to another activity.", could provide an example? Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: @Thanos: See [the docs for `ActivityOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html).

Comment: Yeah you are right, there are so many options to pass around it would make it a very very long example. Thanks for pointing out to the link.

Comment: @Thanos: It's more that I have never used it, nor have I seen it used, so I don't have any examples handy.

Answer (score 16):

> I am sure that I am missing something

I suspect you misunderstand how the result thing works.

Let's suppose you have a `HomeActivity` and a `SettingsActivity`. `HomeActivity` starts a `SettingsActivity` with some parameters and wants to know some result. Here's how it works:

#### HomeActivity

This is how you open the `SettingsActivity`:

```
public void openSettings() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("myParam", 1);
    startActivityForResult(i, 10);
}
```

This is the call you receive when `SettingsActivity` is closed:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 10) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get result from the result intent.
            String result = data.getStringExtra("myResult");

            // Do something with result...
        }
    }
}
```

#### SettingsActivity

This is just the necessary bit. Reads the input, builds the output and closes itself. I hope it's enough for a demonstration.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retrieve the parameter.
    int param = getIntent().getIntExtra("myParam");

    // Get a result somewhere.
    String resultValue = "RESULT=" + param;

    // Build a result intent and post it back.
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("myResult", resultValue);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}
```

See this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html.

Comment: Yeah I miss understood how to use it because I am new to Android completely and I was trying to build something a bit complicated. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Thanks for answer