# Passing bundle instance to place picker intent

Tags: java, android, bundle, google-places-api

I am working on an android app whose main purpose is to update the working location of the employees by admin. Now when I want to change/update the location of an employee from my recycler view(list of employees connected with my UserManagerAdapter), I have to pass the user name of that employee to the place picker intent so that when the admin pick the desired location, the database of that user will be changed accordingly.

My Steps(2 Steps)

1. I have passed the username to the place picker intent as bundle.

My UserManagerAdapter

```
     holder.locationTv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            launchPicker(data.get(position).getUserName());
        }
    });

    private void launchPicker(String userName) {
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    bundle.putString(USERNAME,userName);
    try {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(builder.build(fragment.getActivity()),PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST,bundle);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

2. I received the location request inside of a fragment and update the location of that particular user

My ManageUserFragment

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(getContext(),data);
            address = place.getAddress().toString();
            String latLng = place.getLatLng().toString();
            latLang = latLng;

            //update user's decided location
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            String userName = bundle.getString(USERNAME);// it returns null, Why?
            updateLocation(latLang,userName);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), latLng, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), getContext().getText(R.string.locationError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

My constant is

```
public static final String USERNAME="Username";
```

Now,

My problem is

> Why bundle.getString(USERNAME) always return null?
>
> How to pass data to place picker intent so that we can receive it in
>   onActivityResult ?

Comment: Just asking to make sure,  `onActuvityResult` is called? And you override it in your activity as well?

Comment: @LieForBananas Yes, it is calling properly and I have checked that it returns null by applying breakpoints there.

Answer (score 0):

After replicating your case and researching for a little bit, I found out that the third parameter in `startActivityForResult()` is not used to pass a bundle of values to the `onActivityResult`, it's used to pass options to Android itself, you can find those [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions.html). So if you want to pass any data you have to use an intent with `putExtra("USERNAME", username)`, and you can retrieve it with `getStringExtra("USERNAME")`. It's explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35417146/7915814) answer as well.